# how to put javascript variable in php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I need to add JavaScript variable to PHP array, my code is below and `var date1` is JavaScript variable.

**Code**

```
$date1="2018-08-02";
$date=explode("-",$date1);
```

My JavaSript section is here

```
var date1=new Date(<?=$date[0].",".$date[1].",".$date[2]?>);
date1 place to index of array x
$incoming[$i] = array("x" =>+date1 , "y" => $total_inc);
$outgoing[$i] = array("x" => +date1, "y" => $total_out);
```

In this situation the value is `return 0`.

Comment: make a request to server with get or post then receive them as $_GET or $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. JS code is executed after PHP finished executing own code. You can pass data from js to php by ajax or by setting a cookie.

Comment: thanks for your comment, how to write the  normal php date format (2017-11-24) to javascript date format like Mon Jul 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) ,

Comment: use date('r') in PHP

Comment: thanks , but its return today's date i need  2017-11-24 how ?

Comment: use date("r", strtotime('2017-11-24'));

Comment: its not in format like Mon Jul 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) .

Comment: how can convert php date format like - new Date(2016, 0, 1), its a javascript date format